# Java Spring application won't run in debug mode

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis

I'm a frontend developer so my knowledge of Java, Spring and IntelliJ is virtually zero.

I accidentally deleted my company's repo on my local machine so I re-cloned it back from GitHub. I was unable to click the "debug" button as it was grayed out so I asked a colleague what their Run/Debug configurations were and [added it to my editor](https://cln.sh/OZ9y6T).

Normally, I would click on "debug" and it would run and work with the frontend, but now when I run it this is the error I receive:

updated based on Kaj Hejer recommendation:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:60174', transport: 'socket'
2021-03-31 13:02:22.350  INFO ['casino-api':main::] c.company.casinoapi.CasinoApiApplication - Starting CasinoApiApplication on Marks-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 7352 (/Users/work/Documents/casino-api/target/classes started by work in /Users/work/Documents/casino-api)
2021-03-31 13:02:22.353  INFO ['casino-api':main::] c.company.casinoapi.CasinoApiApplication - The following profiles are active: local
2021-03-31 13:02:23.781  INFO ['casino-api':main::] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2021-03-31 13:02:23.781  INFO ['casino-api':main::] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService - Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-03-31 13:02:23.781  INFO ['casino-api':main::] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine - Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.31]
2021-03-31 13:02:23.870  INFO ['casino-api':main::] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-03-31 13:02:23.871  INFO ['casino-api':main::] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1480 ms
2021-03-31 13:02:24.171  INFO ['casino-api':main::] io.lettuce.core.EpollProvider - Starting without optional epoll library
2021-03-31 13:02:24.171  INFO ['casino-api':main::] io.lettuce.core.KqueueProvider - Starting without optional kqueue library
2021-03-31 13:02:24.418  INFO ['casino-api':main::] o.f.core.internal.license.VersionPrinter - Flyway Community Edition 6.0.8 by Redgate
2021-03-31 13:02:24.423  INFO ['casino-api':main::] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-03-31 13:02:24.483  INFO ['casino-api':main::] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-03-31 13:02:24.500  INFO ['casino-api':main::] o.f.c.internal.database.DatabaseFactory - Database: jdbc:mysql://0.0.0.0:4306/api (MySQL 10.4)
2021-03-31 13:02:24.570  INFO ['casino-api':main::] o.f.core.internal.command.DbValidate - Successfully validated 3 migrations (execution time 00:00.019s)
2021-03-31 13:02:24.583  INFO ['casino-api':main::] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate - Current version of schema `api`: 2
2021-03-31 13:02:24.583  WARN ['casino-api':main::] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate - Schema `api` has a version (2) that is newer than the latest available migration (1) !
2021-03-31 13:02:24.585  INFO ['casino-api':main::] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate - Schema `api` is up to date. No migration necessary.
2021-03-31 13:02:24.674  INFO ['casino-api':main::] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-03-31 13:02:24.741  INFO ['casino-api':main::] org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.10.Final}
2021-03-31 13:02:24.871  INFO ['casino-api':main::] org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2021-03-31 13:02:24.981  INFO ['casino-api':main::] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
2021-03-31 13:02:25.139  WARN ['casino-api':main::] org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - HHH000457: Joined inheritance hierarchy [com.company.casinoapi.model.game.GameLog] defined explicit @DiscriminatorColumn.  Legacy Hibernate behavior was to ignore the @DiscriminatorColumn.  However, as part of issue HHH-6911 we now apply the explicit @DiscriminatorColumn.  If you would prefer the legacy behavior, enable the `hibernate.discriminator.ignore_explicit_for_joined` setting (hibernate.discriminator.ignore_explicit_for_joined=true)
2021-03-31 13:02:25.893  INFO ['casino-api':main::] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator - HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-03-31 13:02:26.260  WARN ['casino-api':main::] o.s.b.a.o.j.JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration - spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-03-31 13:02:26.502  WARN ['casino-api':main::] o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'gameReportController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jwtAuthenticator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'globalJWTConfig' defined in class path resource [com/company/casinoapi/config/JWTAuthConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.company.casinoapi.bean.JWTAuthenticator]: Factory method 'globalJWTConfig' threw exception; nested exception is java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: src/main/resources/secrets/api-engine-secret.key
2021-03-31 13:02:26.505  INFO ['casino-api':main::] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-03-31 13:02:26.522  INFO ['casino-api':main::] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2021-03-31 13:02:26.550  INFO ['casino-api':main::] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService - Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-03-31 13:02:26.564 ERROR ['casino-api':main::] o.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'gameReportController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jwtAuthenticator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'globalJWTConfig' defined in class path resource [com/company/casinoapi/config/JWTAuthConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.company.casinoapi.bean.JWTAuthenticator]: Factory method 'globalJWTConfig' threw exception; nested exception is java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: src/main/resources/secrets/api-engine-secret.key
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at com.company.casinoapi.CasinoApiApplication.main(CasinoApiApplication.java:10)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'globalJWTConfig' defined in class path resource [com/company/casinoapi/config/JWTAuthConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.company.casinoapi.bean.JWTAuthenticator]: Factory method 'globalJWTConfig' threw exception; nested exception is java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: src/main/resources/secrets/api-engine-secret.key
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:484)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.company.casinoapi.bean.JWTAuthenticator]: Factory method 'globalJWTConfig' threw exception; nested exception is java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: src/main/resources/secrets/api-engine-secret.key
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651)
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: src/main/resources/secrets/api-engine-secret.key
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:219)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:370)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:421)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:420)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:155)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedReader(Files.java:2838)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(Files.java:3329)
    at com.company.casinoapi.bean.JWTAuthenticator.<init>(JWTAuthenticator.java:28)
    at com.company.casinoapi.config.JWTAuthConfig.globalJWTConfig(JWTAuthConfig.java:17)
    at com.company.casinoapi.config.JWTAuthConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8d9d3081.CGLIB$globalJWTConfig$0(<generated>)
    at com.company.casinoapi.config.JWTAuthConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8d9d3081$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f2f1d21b.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
    at com.company.casinoapi.config.JWTAuthConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8d9d3081.globalJWTConfig(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:60174', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Is it Maven or Gradle project? In the project's root folder run `mvn clean install` for Maven, `./gradle clean` for Gradle, and run/debug the project. If these things are not working, please [edit] the question and post `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` file here

Comment: It's a Maven project. `mvn clean install` says mvn command not found

Comment: `secrets/api-engine-secret.key` sounds like sth you wouldn't commit to a code repo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the stacktrace you can see the following:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [io.lettuce.core.api.StatefulRedisConnection]: Factory method 'connection' threw exception; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to 0.0.0.0:6380
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651)
    ... 96 common frames omitted
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to 0.0.0.0:6380
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:7
```

It looks like you app is trying to connect to a redis-server. I suggest you hear with your colleague how they start the redis-server.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it to me. I normally run Redis and MariaDB in Docker but forgot to do so in this instance. I've updated my post to reflect the new output I'm getting after running those containers. Can you verify this is a secret key issue?

Comment: Yes, seems like you are missing the file ```api-engine-secret.key```. btw, can you please change my firstname from "Kay" to "Kaj"? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add `api-engine-secret.key` file to your project in the path `src/main/resources/secrets`, maybe this file not pushed to GitHub repository, So you need to get it from a colleague.